# How do I tell that OSX is done with a file from the CLI?

Tags: macos, shell, file-transfer

When you copy a file in the new versions of OSX you get a bunch of placeholders:

[image]

I'm trying to automate some stuff from shell scripts and want to know when OSX is done with these files, however I can't seem to figure out how.  They just look like normal files with partial or zero sizes.  I could guess by looking at the last modified time stamp, but that's kinda ugly and not always accurate.

Comment: Have you seen [How to monitor file access for an OS X application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/how-to-monitor-file-access-for-an-os-x-application)

Comment: @AndrewMorton -- The problem is consistency.  While a file is copying there's lsof activity that I can snoop.  But if something hangs, the file gets interrupted, etc there's no active file activity, yet OSX still has some sort of a "lock" on the file.  I'm trying to figure out what that is.

For instance I have a file that OSX says is about 2/3rds done copying, but the drive got disconnected.  Anything I can do from sh tells me it's done.  It's > 0 bytes, no lsof activity, and the last modified date was hours ago.

Comment: Would a [try..catch equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009364/is-there-a-try-catch-command-in-bash) help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton -- Not really.  The current issue is that I have no way to know if these files are partially copied or completed.  Obviously my computer somehow knows!